# Concatenate strings from multiple records in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, string, teradata, aggregation

I have a list of merchants that do business in different states.

```
Merch    State

A          NC

A          FL

B          CA

B          VA
```

Instead of returning four records I want to group by Merch but concatenate the strings of the states so that the output looks like

```
Merch      States

A           NC,FL

B           CA,VA
```

I'm having a lot of trouble translating the response in this answer for my issue
[Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

I also cannot get String_agg to work, I'm not sure it works in Teradata. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741925/aggregation-by-timestamp/23770295?noredirect=1#23770295

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `xml_agg()` built in function in Teradata. This doesn't translate well from SQL Server which is why you are having issues with those two links.

```
SELECT merch, TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(States || ',' ORDER BY States) (VARCHAR(500))))
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It seems to be a great start. I pulled the top 200 and in the Teradata Answerset it shows "XMLAGG((Merch_state001.xml and so forth. These were saved to files on my computer, which are the correct string if I open them in Notepad.   I don't really understand what these XML files are but can extract the text from them?

Comment: It's not so much that it's XML. We are just borrowing the `xml_agg` function here to generate a comma delimited list which is just a string. If it's giving you oddball outputs you could toss a CAST() around that xmlagg like `CAST(XMLAGG(States || ',' ORDER BY States) AS VARCHAR(500))` so you are definitely dealing with a varchar field type in your output.

Comment: The syntax for casting XMLAGG is a little funky, to me at least.  This works for me:  `TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(state || ',' ORDER BY state ) (VARCHAR(10000))))`.

Comment: 'select top 20 merch,  translate(xmlagg(merch_state ||  ','  ORDER BY merch_state) as VARCHAR(500))
from table1 
group by 1;  '                                                                                                               Is throwing this error for me http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035_1096_112K/Database.27.1563.html any ideas? Thanks so much, Sorry I have no idea how to format this.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the suggestion from @Andrew  I believe that should do the trick