# Join Comment Rows into Single Row

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

My query is listing out comments in sequence lines. I am hoping to combine them into one comment column instead of having multiple rows for one PO. Here is my query now:

```
SELECT  PO,
    SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
    COMMENT_LINE
FROM Database
```

Which is returning:

| PO | SEQUENCE NUMBER | COMMENT LINE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8582959 | 1 | COMMENT LINE 1 |
| 8582959 | 2 | COMMENT LINE 2 |
| 8582960 | 1 | COMMENT LINE 1 |

I am hoping for it to return the two comment lines concatenated with a ', ' between them like this:

| PO | COMMENT LINE |
| --- | --- |
| 8582959 | COMMENT LINE 1, COMMENT LINE 2 |
| 8582960 | COMMENT LINE 1 |

I tried using CONCAT, but couldn't figure out how to get the lines to join since they are in the same columns. I think maybe an inner join would work, but I have never used one and am not quite sure on how to format. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is available on Teradata but You can try using `string_agg()` aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT
  po,
  STRING_AGG(comment_line, ', ')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY po;
```

Comment: No STRING_AGG - but can be done leveraging XML_AGG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306260/concatenate-strings-from-multiple-records-in-teradata-sql/45306398#45306398 or NPATH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683088/teradata-results-with-duplicate-values-converted-into-comma-delimited-strings/63685218#63685218 functions (or even recursive query - but that's usually less performant).