# Group products into one cell - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string-aggregation

I've this table **Orders** :

```
+-----+--------------+
| id_order | products| 
+----------+---------+
|  1  |    product 1  | 
+-----+--------------+
|  1  |    product 49| 
+-----+--------------+
|  1  |    product 12| 
+-----+--------------+
|  2  |    Product 1 | 
+-----+--------------+
|  3  |    Product 50| 
+-----+--------------+
|  4  |    Product 42| 
+-----+--------------+
```

In my SQL query I want to group products like this :

```
 +-----+-------------------------------------+
| id_order | products                        | 
+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1  |    product 1, product 49, product 12  | 
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|  2  |    Product 1                         | 
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|  3  |    Product 50                        | 
+-----+--------------------------------------+
|  4  |    Product 42                        | 
+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

How can I regroup these products in one cell ? using GROUP_CONCAT ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: *How can I regroup these products in one cell ? using GROUP_CONCAT ?* True. With GROUP BY, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP\_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT` which is inbuilt method in Mysql, **this only works for Mysql server.**

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE Products (
  Id INTEGER,
  product TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1, 'Product 1');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1, 'Product 2');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1, 'Product 3');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (2, 'Product 9');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (3, 'Product 10');

-- fetch 
SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(product) FROM Products GROUP BY Id
```

Output:

```
1|Product 1,Product 2,Product 3
2|Product 9
3|Product 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using STRING_AGG() grouping function if available on Your DB.

Check here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484961/join-comment-rows-into-single-row/69487705#69487705][1]